# Switching word on awt based applet's window box

Tags: java, applet

I want to print a text on the applet's window eg. Hello, then after 1 second the word should change eg. World so my text should change between Hello and World with 1 sec of delay. Any suggestions?

I used if else if to change the txt in update()

```
if(txt.equals("Hello"))
    txt="World";

else if(txt.equals("World"))
     txt="Hello";

else
      System.out.println("Invalid txt");
```

This did not work. I think it's because strings are immutable.
then I used i++ in update() and changed paint()

```
if(i%2==0)
   g.drawString(txt1,50,50);
else
   g.drawString(txt2,50,50);
```

this did not work either. So any other suggestions.

Comment: *"Any suggestions?"* Use Swing instead. Dump applets. Or in more detail: 1) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT components in favor of Swing. 2) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web).

Comment: This is a problem question. I am not using awt to develop anything. If I could come up with a solution to this problem may be  I might learn something new about java's awt features or any function I am not aware of. And if this is impossible to execute through awt, I would like to know why and what is the limitation that prevents it.

Comment: Well good luck with that. There's nothing from AWT components worth learning. Applets are dead. If you can work it out from a custom painted `JPanel` in a `JFrame` it's probable you can apply the lesson back to the AWT based applet. If you want to pursue that, post a Swing based [mcve].

Comment: To expand on that, I'd use a **Swing** based `Timer` - there's another thing not provide for (but still usable in) an AWT based `Applet`.